# VBA XMLHTTP 'Out-of-memory' state

Tags: vba, performance, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, out-of-memory

Here is a piece of code that should connect to a web page with contents as follows: `link1, description1, otherdata1, link2, description2, otherdata2, ..., linkN, descriptionN, otherdataN` where N is 30 000 +.

From these links, the program finds one link of interest using regex, goes to that link, and downloads a file from there.

My problem is: at htmlWebInterfaceXML.send the program frequently, but not always, runs out of memory ('out-of-memory' error). It is difficult for me to test different solutions because normally the program runs smoothly, and it is difficult to notice changes if any.

Additional info:

- It runs smoothly on some PCs and does not work for others
- It usually runs until afternoon and throws an error then

Other infos that may be helpful:

- the code shown is a private method of class and the class itself is a small part of the source code
- other subs called which I do not explain are not relevant and run smoothly, the probelm always appears at htmlWebInterfaceXML.send.

One guess of mine is that I have declared local variable inside of a function that holds a very large object and can cause a stack overflow but it seems unlikely as VBA should handle those things on its own. **Maybe you see a problem that I don't?** Thank you.

```
Private Sub FileUpload()
    ' THE FUNCTION CANNOT BE CONNECTING FOR EACH CONTRACT ID! WILL TAKE TOO MUCH TIME - NEED TO ALTER
    Dim member As Variant
    Dim byteCounter As Byte
    Dim byteMaxID As Byte
    Dim strPathToXMLFile As String
    Dim strURLToXMLFile    
    Dim strXMLFileStorageName As String    
    Dim domdocXMLText As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim clctStrFoundMatches As New Collection
    Dim clctInternalIDs As New Collection
    Dim vrntContractID As Variant
    Dim htmlHTMLMainPageXMLInterface As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlTagElement As Variant
    Dim htmclctFoundXMLs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim htmlWebInterfaceXML As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim intNumberOfTradeUnderProcessing As Integer

    UpdateProgressStatus "LOADING SERVER WITH SOURCE XML..." '<----------- UPDATE PROGRESS!


    '----------------------> OPEN AND LOAD THE WEB SERVER, AND STORE ITS HTML INTO AN OBJECT
    Set htmlWebInterfaceXML = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    With htmlWebInterfaceXML
        .Open "GET", p_cstrWebInterfaceXMLRootDirectory, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic" & Base64Encode( _
                                          p_cstrXMLWebInterfaceAuthenticationUser & ":" & p_cstrXMLWebInterfaceAuthenticationPassword)
        .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
    End With
    htmlHTMLMainPageXMLInterface.body.innerHTML = htmlWebInterfaceXML.responseText ' how much text is the htmldocument able to store??
    Set htmlWebInterfaceXML = Nothing

    SetUpDirectory                               ' ------------> create or set directory where to store XML files

    If Me.ContractiDs.Count <> Me.MailParts.Count And Me.ContractiDs.Count <> Me.MailParts.Count * 2 Then
        Err.Raise 1504, "FileUpload", p_cstrError1504Message
    Else
        For Each vrntContractID In Me.ContractiDs

            intNumberOfTradeUnderProcessing = intNumberOfTradeUnderProcessing + 1
            UpdateProgressStatus "LOADING XML FOR THE TRADE NUMBER " & intNumberOfTradeUnderProcessing & "..." ' ----------------> UPDATE STATUS BAR

            ' ------------------------> find the tags containing the needed contract id in their names

            Set htmclctFoundXMLs = htmlHTMLMainPageXMLInterface.getElementsByTagName("a")
            Set clctStrFoundMatches = New Collection
            For Each htmlTagElement In htmclctFoundXMLs
                If htmlTagElement.getAttribute("href") Like "*" & vrntContractID & "*" Then
                    clctStrFoundMatches.Add htmlTagElement
                End If
            Next htmlTagElement

            If clctStrFoundMatches.Count = 0 Then Err.Raise 1506, "FileUpload", p_cstrError1506Message

            ' -----------------------> exclude the archives from the collection

            byteCounter = 0
            For byteCounter = 1 To clctStrFoundMatches.Count
                If blnContainsPattern("\.gz$", clctStrFoundMatches(byteCounter).innerText) Then
                    clctStrFoundMatches.Remove byteCounter
                End If
            Next byteCounter

            ' ----------------------> extract the contract ids and find the last contract id

            Set clctInternalIDs = New Collection

            For Each member In clctStrFoundMatches
                clctInternalIDs.Add strReturnSingleMatch("\d{9}", member.innerText)
                If clctInternalIDs(clctInternalIDs.Count) = "False" Then Err.Raise 1505, "FileUpload", p_cstrError1505Message
            Next member
            byteMaxID = FindMaximum(clctInternalIDs)
            strPathToXMLFile = clctStrFoundMatches(byteMaxID).innerText

            ' -----------------------> check whether such file exists, and, if not, download it

            If blnFileExists(strPathToXMLFile, p_cstrXMLDestination) Then
            Else
                strURLToXMLFile = p_cstrWebInterfaceXMLRootDirectory & strPathToXMLFile
                Set htmlWebInterfaceXML = Nothing: Set htmlWebInterfaceXML = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
                htmlWebInterfaceXML.Open "GET", strURLToXMLFile, False
                htmlWebInterfaceXML.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic" & Base64Encode( _
                                                                     p_cstrXMLWebInterfaceAuthenticationUser & ":" & p_cstrXMLWebIntervaceAuthenticationPassword)
                htmlWebInterfaceXML.send
                With domdocXMLText
                    .validateOnParse = False
                    .async = False
                End With
                domdocXMLText.LoadXML htmlWebInterfaceXML.responseText
                domdocXMLText.Save p_cstrXMLDestination & "\" & strPathToXMLFile
            End If
        Next vrntContractID

    End If

    Set htmlHTMLMainPageXMLInterface = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: 4) You can usually remove loops like _If htmlTagElement.getAttribute("href") Like "*" & vrntContractID & "*"_   with much more efficient CSS selectors i.e. querySelectorAll("href*=" & vrntContractID) .... Back to point 2) not actually even sure from the above if you are regexing through html or just returned strings but reckon there still is probably a better way with the source HTML to extract specific links.

Comment: @QHarr hey, thanks for responding. I regex through html because it's poorly tagged. In particular, dates and times of links which are critical for me are not enclosed in tags at all but 'hang in space'. Subs that are not shown perform greatly within miliseconds and what they do is not relevant at all (actually, the code shown is maybe 0.5 % of the whole source code). The problem always appears at htmlWebInterfaceXML.send. Thank you for the valuable comments

Comment: @QHarr thank you! Actually this sub is a private method of a class. In brief, the class parses an EMail, does a bunch of stuff with its contents (unfortunately, also with regex) and also uploads necessary files as shown in this sub. Wether this is run from the form or not, depends on the user behavior: users drag-and-drop an EMail in which case an event fires, or also launch the sequence of calls to the class from a button-click in the user form. This class itself is instantiated within the main() sub though. 
Hope this was descriptive and yes, the web page is a NIGHTMARE

Comment: @QHarr referring to your last comment: it also takes a long time to load that page from IE, and i don't really know why, 30 000 + must not be that much fro HTML? I would be happy if we could solve the 'Out-of-memory' problem

Comment: @QHarr a good point, indeed. As far as I can remember it now: becuase the part of the code you've mentioned is in the for-loop, and I am using the same htmlWebInterfaceXML object to store the responses from different html addresses, I clear it out to store the new response in it. For now, I am not really sure why I cleared it out before sending the new request. P.S. in this case, the htmlWebInterfaceXML sends request to one of those links that I've been looping thorough. The response is small and it runs properly. So it throws 'Out-of-memory' only at the first 'request.send' at the top of code

Comment: @QHarr I guess, when I didn't clear out the object, it stored the new response on top of the previous response. Again, I am not quite sure but this must have been the reason why I added 'set .. = nothing'.

Comment: which version of Office are you running? Sounds like potential memory leak - as indeed seems you are trying to handle. http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/05/solve-vba-potentially-massive-memory.html    XHR (don't know about VBA library implementation ) from [JS point of view](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/08/) is prone to this where circular references and reference counting are involved.

Comment: exactly but I have no idea why and where. I am running MC Office Professional Plus 2010 on corporate PCs. thanks, checking the link

Comment: older versions of office had the following memory leak issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-customize/excel-2016-runs-out-of-memory-when-calculating/d2c59e11-579c-4285-8c50-0a484921ac53?auth=1 I am not very experienced with monitoring though I know basic process level can be done through PerfMon on Windows. You might get assistance from the [RD crew](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) on that - though they tend to be online from early pm due to timezone.

Comment: @QHarr thank you again, I'll check all the links and be back with an update in some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that i solved. my script ran through a server and looked for a string in thousands of text files.

The way i solved it is (using ascync ServerXMLHTTP60) setting an if condition in the response handler to ABORT the xmlhttp object. After i was done comparing data, the object would get "dropped" out of memory, and now i can query (virtually) any amount of data. (took me about a month to test a lot of solution, and this was the right one)

This might work for you, so just add htmlWebInterfaceXML.abort after you are done with that data set.

Hope this helps! Cheers!